# Use ADFS while maintaining forms authentication

Tags: forms, authentication, adfs

I have a question regarding ADFS and forms authentication. I currently maintain a database of users and have built a somewhat complex claims-based system around it. All of my clients use forms authentication to access my website (ASP.NET). Recently one of my clients expressed a desire to switch to a single sign on model. I would like to use ADFS to accomplish this. My question is how do I go about using both forms authentication and ADFS at the same time. I need all of my other clients to still be able to access the site using forms authentication. I know this cannot be a rare problem, but I can't seem to find any good answers to the question. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

using ADFS V2.0 allows both types of authentication, windows and forms and both relies on the active directory that means you must save and keep all the users data in the active directory.

pleases see http://www.richardawilson.com/2010/10/adfs-20-login-page.html

if you need the ADFS reads the users and credentials from another source than the Active directory,
in that case you must implement a custom claim provider and configure the ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I totally understand the question but ADFS can use FBA - [AD FS 2.0: How to Change the Local Authentication Type](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1600.aspx).

Is your "complex claims-based system" a STS? If it is, just federate with ADFS.

If it isn't, have a look at [Thinktecture IdentityServer](http://thinktecture.github.com/).

Comment: So if I want company A to be able to authenticate against their own active directory, and I want company B to be able to use forms authentication to access my website, what should I do? Is that the case where I can federate with ADFS if i'm using an STS?